# Merge one branch to another branch

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, package.json

I'm currently working on two local branches. Normally what I do is I make changes in branchA, commit it. Then switch to branch B and merge A into B (because B is the one I want to push to Github and merge into main). So, my question is, when I npm install for A, will B have this package too? the same question applied to npm uninstall.

Comment: What do you mean "have this package"? The change to the package file (and lock file, assuming it's version controlled) will be there, yes; that's part of the changes you've merged. But the node_modules directory is generally _not_ under version control, so the actual installed modules don't change as you switch branches.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to speak about merging one branch *into* another branch, e.g. "I merge branch A into B" - saying "merging with" is a little unclear, as there's always a direction that merges occur - one branch is merged *into* another

For your case, if you've installed `package-x` in branch A, and merged branch A into branch B, then branch B will have the updates in `package.json`

Whether the package is installed or not is another thing:

- have you run `npm install` from branch A?
- are you ignoring `node_modules` in your project (it should be in `.gitignore`)?

If you have run `npm install` when branch A was active, and `node_modules` is in `.gitignore`, `package-x` will be installed regardless of which branch you switch to thereafter